# Warning: Unknown: 1 result set(s) not freed. Use mysql_free_result to free result sets which were requested using mysql_query() in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this warning everything us working fine the user DTA is going to mysql but when I user login I get this warning idk how to remove it and I also used this but it get me more errors and I searched all google but didn't find a solid solution to fix this so I cane here pls just answer question don't invite or relate this question to any other anyway this is the statement I used

```
<?php mysql_free_result($result); ?>
```

Error

```
Warning: Unknown: 1 result set(s) not freed. Use mysql_free_result to free result sets which were requested using mysql_query() in Unknown on line 0
```

Code

```
<style>
<?php include 'signin.css'; ?>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="signup.js"></script>
<?php
//signin.php
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';
 

 
//first, check if the user is already signed in. If that is the case, there is no need to display this page
if(isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) && $_SESSION['signed_in'] == true)
{
    echo 'You are already signed in, you can <a href="signout.php">sign out</a> if you want.';
}
else
{
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
    {
        /*the form hasn't been posted yet, display it
          note that the action="" will cause the form to post to the same page it is on */
        echo '<form action="" method="post"  >
<div class="all" >
<div class="container" >
<div class="first" >
<h2>SIGN IN</h2>
</div>
<div class="user" >
<input class="use"  type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="user_name" required>
</div>
<div class="userimg" >
<img  src="user.png" style="height:2em;width:2em;" >
</div>
<div class="pass" >
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"  name="user_pass" minlength="8" required  >
<img src="lock.png" >
</div>
<div class="show">
<img src="visible.png" id="visible" class="visible" onclick="myFunction()">
<img src="invisible.png" id="invisible"  class="invisible" onclick="mynot()" >
</div>
<div class="check" >
<input type="checkbox" required >
</div>
<div class="box" >
<p>I accept all <a href="#" >terms</a> and <a href="#" >privacy</a>.</p>
</div>
<div class="submit" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="submit()" value="Sign in">
</div>
<div class="close" >
<input type="button" value="Back"  >
</div>
<div class="log" >
dont have an account? <a href="#" >Login</a>
</div>
<div class="organic" >
<img src="logo.png" class="organicpe" >
</div>
<div>
<h2 class="back" ><a href="#" >Go Back</a></h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>';
    }
    else
    {
        /* so, the form has been posted, we'll process the data in three steps:
            1.  Check the data
            2.  Let the user refill the wrong fields (if necessary)
            3.  Verify if the data is correct and return the correct response
        */
        $errors = array(); /* declare the array for later use */
         
        if(!isset($_POST['user_name']))
        {
            $errors[] = 'The username field must not be empty.';
        }
         
        if(!isset($_POST['user_pass']))
        {
            $errors[] = 'The password field must not be empty.';
        }
         
        if(!empty($errors)) /*check for an empty array, if there are errors, they're in this array (note the ! operator)*/
        {
            echo 'Uh-oh.. a couple of fields are not filled in correctly..';
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($errors as $key => $value) /* walk through the array so all the errors get displayed */
            {
                echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>'; /* this generates a nice error list */
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        else
        {
            //the form has been posted without errors, so save it
            //notice the use of mysql_real_escape_string, keep everything safe!
            //also notice the sha1 function which hashes the password
            $sql = "SELECT 
                        user_id,
                        user_name,
                        user_level
                    FROM
                        Users
                    WHERE
                        user_name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "'
                    AND
                        user_pass = '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "'";
                         
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if(!$result)
            {
                //something went wrong, display the error
                echo 'Something went wrong while signing in. Please try again later.';
                //echo mysql_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
            }
            else
            {
                //the query was successfully executed, there are 2 possibilities
                //1. the query returned data, the user can be signed in
                //2. the query returned an empty result set, the credentials were wrong
                if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
                {
                    echo 'You have supplied a wrong user/password combination. Please try again.';
                }
                else
                {
                    //set the $_SESSION['signed_in'] variable to TRUE
                    $_SESSION['signed_in'] = true;
                     
                    //we also put the user_id and user_name values in the $_SESSION, so we can use it at various pages
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['user_id']    = $row['user_id'];
                        $_SESSION['user_name']  = $row['user_name'];
                        $_SESSION['user_level'] = $row['user_level'];
                    }
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
//set the $_SESSION['signed_in'] variable to TRUE
$_SESSION['signed_in'] = true;                  
//we also put the user_id and user_name values in the $_SESSION, so we can use it at various pages
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['user_name']; 
}
                     }
                    echo '<h3>Welcome, ' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '. <a href="index.php">Proceed to the forum overview</a>.</h1>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are _deprecated_! [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Hmm I think I should use mysqli

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: Stop! Are you still using PHP 5? Do you know how irresponsible this is? Focus your efforts on migrating this project to PHP 7 or even PHP 8. You can use PDO to connect to the database. Don't bother with mysqli.